email_verification_code is not entered
function custom_input_shortcode( $atts ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit_custom_input'] ) && $_POST['submit_custom_input'] ) {
        $new_first_name = isset( $_POST['custom_input_first_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_input_first_name'] ) : '';
        $new_last_name = isset( $_POST['custom_input_last_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_input_last_name'] ) : '';
        $new_email = isset( $_POST['custom_input_email'] ) ? sanitize_email( $_POST['custom_input_email'] ) : '';

        if ( ! preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $new_first_name ) ) {
            echo 'Invalid first name. Please enter alphabetic characters only.';
            return;
        }

        if ( ! preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $new_last_name ) ) {
            echo 'Invalid last name. Please enter alphabetic characters only.';
            return;
        }

        if ( ! is_email( $new_email ) ) {
            echo 'Invalid email address. Please enter a valid email.';
            return;
        }

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        
        $current_first_name = $current_user->first_name;
        $current_last_name = $current_user->last_name;
        $current_email = $current_user->user_email;

        if ( ! empty( $new_email ) && $new_email !== $current_email ) {
            if ( email_exists( $new_email ) ) {
                echo 'Email address is already in use. Please enter a different email.';
                return;
            }
            $verification_code = generate_verification_code($current_user->ID);

            $email_subject = 'Email Verification Code';
            $email_message = 'Your email verification code is: ' . $verification_code;
            wp_mail( $new_email, $email_subject, $email_message );

            update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'new_email_temp', $new_email );

            echo '<form method="post" action="">
            <label for="email_verification_code">Verification Code:</label>
            <input type="text" id="verification_code" name="verification_code" required>
            <input type="submit" name="email_verification_code" value="Verify"></form>';
            return;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['email_verification_code'] ) ) {
            $submitted_code = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email_verification_code'] );

            $stored_code = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'email_verification_code', true );
            $verification_timestamp = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'verification_timestamp', true );

            if ( time() - $verification_timestamp > 15 * 60 ) {
                echo 'Verification code has expired. Please request a new one.';
                delete_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'email_verification_code' );
                delete_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'verification_timestamp' );
                return;
            }

            if ( $submitted_code === $stored_code ) {
                $new_email_temp = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'new_email_temp', true );
                wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => $new_email_temp ) );

                delete_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'email_verification_code' );
                delete_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'verification_timestamp' );
                delete_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'new_email_temp' );

                echo 'Email address updated successfully.';
                return;
            } else {
                echo 'Invalid verification code. Please enter the correct code.';
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    
    ob_start();
    ?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <label for="custom_input_first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="custom_input_first_name" name="custom_input_first_name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Enter alphabetic characters only" value=[user_firstname] placeholder=[user_firstname]>

    <label for="custom_input_last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="custom_input_last_name" name="custom_input_last_name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Enter alphabetic characters only" value=[user_lastname] placeholder=[user_lastname]>

    <label for="custom_input_email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="custom_input_email" name="custom_input_email" value=[user_email] placeholder=[user_email]>

    <input type="submit" name="submit_custom_input" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_input', 'custom_input_shortcode' );

function generate_verification_code($user_id) {
    delete_user_meta($user_id, 'email_verification_code');
    delete_user_meta($user_id, 'verification_timestamp');

    $verification_code = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'email_verification_code', $verification_code);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'verification_timestamp', time());

    return 100000;
}


When you press the Submit button, the Email Verification Code will be verified and changed. But when I press the send button, no function occurs. It doesn't go into email_verification_code. directly refreshes the page. The goal is to send a verification code to the email when someone wants to change their email address. If the verification code is entered correctly, the email should be changed.

I think you need to take a step back and simplify. Forget everything about email and verification for now. Focus solely on having a form with a single field that performs an HTTP POST to the server, and then finding a way to retrieve that value.
